# Anyone have success configuring react-native-home-indicator?

Tags: react-native, expo, appdelegate

I'm attempting to hide the iOS app home indicator in React Native with no success. Research eventually led me to the react-native-home-indicator package.

[Step 3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-home-indicator?activeTab=readme) of the ReadMe instructs one to configure changes in the **Appdelegate.m**. No such file appears to exist in my project. I cannot confirm, but such a file seems to be a vestige of programming in Xcode? Meanwhile, I created the project in React Native to avoid working in an iOS specific platform. Everything I've developed has been in VSCode up to this point.

Any insight would be appreciated. Avoiding step 3 of the configuration leads to errors in my application once I reference `<PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden />` or `<HomeIndicator autoHidden />`.

(My project uses Expo, if that further muddies the water.)